# How to post a page from asp.net to classic ASP

Tags: asp.net, forms, post, asp-classic, get

I'd like to post some form variables into a classic ASP page. I don't want to have to alter the classic ASP pages, because of the amount of work that would need to be done, and the amount of pages that consume them.

The classic ASP page expects form variables Username and Userpassword to be submitted to them.

```
username = Request.Form("UserName")
userpassword = Request.Form("Userpassword")
```

It then performs various actions and sets up sessions, going into an ASP application.

I want to submit these variables into the page from ASP.NET, but the login control is nested inside usercontrols and templates, so I can't get the form element's names to be "username" and "UserPassword".

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever get this to work posting to a classic asp page?  I have gotten everything to register the keys to the RemotePost object, but can not retrieve them on a classic asp page afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't really "forward" a POST on, like you're wanting to do (in your OP). The client has to initiate the POST to your ASP page(s) (which the code in your second post is doing).

---

Here's the self-POSTing code from your own reply so you can mark an answer, like you suggested:

```
public class  RemotePost{
     private  System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection Inputs 
     = new  System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection() ;

    public string  Url  =  "" ;
    public string  Method  =  "post" ;
    public string  FormName  =  "form1" ;

    public void  Add( string  name, string value ){
        Inputs.Add(name, value ) ;
     }

     public void  Post(){
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear() ;

         System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write( "<html><head>" ) ;

         System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write( string .Format( "</head><body onload=\"document.{0}.submit()\">" ,FormName)) ;

         System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write( string .Format( "<form name=\"{0}\" method=\"{1}\" action=\"{2}\" >" ,

        FormName,Method,Url)) ;
            for ( int  i = 0 ; i< Inputs.Keys.Count ; i++){
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write( string .Format( "<input name=\"{0}\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"{1}\">" ,Inputs.Keys[i],Inputs[Inputs.Keys[i]])) ;
         }
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write( "</form>" ) ;
         System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write( "</body></html>" ) ;
         System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End() ;
     }
}
```

Comment: This is a good post. If you put a description of the answer with the relevant code from below i'll mark it as the answer (you can't mark your own answers as the accepted answer) - that is unless anyone else gets a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the asp.net login control (if you are).

Use simple html for the user name/password textboxes in your user control ***without*** runat="server":

```
<input type="text" name="UserName" />

<input type="password" name="Userpassword" />

<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" PostBackUrl="Destination.asp" />
```

Set the PostBackUrl property on the button to you classic asp url and all should be fine.

Comment: Okay - but I'm guessing this means I can't do anything server side with the valuses for username and userpassword prior to submitting them?

Answer (score 0):

I found this on [another site](http://www.jigar.net/articles/viewhtmlcontent78.aspx).

I will build up a small form with just the variables you want, and output it to the client and submit itself. It's pretty neat, but it comes with the problem of breaking the back button, and sending the password back to the client in a form unencrypted.

```
public class  RemotePost{
     private  System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection Inputs 
     = new  System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection() ;

    public string  Url  =  "" ;
    public string  Method  =  "post" ;
    public string  FormName  =  "form1" ;

    public void  Add( string  name, string value ){
        Inputs.Add(name, value ) ;
     }

     public void  Post(){
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear() ;

         System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write( "<html><head>" ) ;

         System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write( string .Format( "</head><body onload=\"document.{0}.submit()\">" ,FormName)) ;

         System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write( string .Format( "<form name=\"{0}\" method=\"{1}\" action=\"{2}\" >" ,

        FormName,Method,Url)) ;
            for ( int  i = 0 ; i< Inputs.Keys.Count ; i++){
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write( string .Format( "<input name=\"{0}\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"{1}\">" ,Inputs.Keys[i],Inputs[Inputs.Keys[i]])) ;
         }
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write( "</form>" ) ;
         System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write( "</body></html>" ) ;
         System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End() ;
     }
}
```

Comment: Don't worry about sending the password back unencrypted - after all, that's the way it came to you. Also, you should put a Submit button and a message on there for non-JS users to click on.

Comment: Thanks Mark. If someone posts the answer in it's entireity, I'll accept the answer.