# Post .Net form data to classic asp page dynamically

Tags: javascript, asp.net, forms, asp-classic

I was asked to research this question at work and I haven't found anything useful.  I understand this is a terrible approach to submitting data, but it's a quick workaround before a full re-build.

I have an .aspx page that does some custom validation on the form submission.  If this passes validation, I want to submit the form to a classic .asp page and retrieve the form values. I was trying to do it via javascript, but that was unsuccessful.

Basically binding the .asp page to the form action and submitting it. Something like;

```
If success = true then
    Dim script As String = "<script>document.forms[0].action='/d_form/Email_BOS_FormConfirm_NET.asp';"
    script += "document.forms[0].submit();"
    script += "</script"
    script += ">"
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.[GetType](), "postform", script)  
End If
```

This is not my formatting, just what i was given to work off of, this posts to the form in the action, but i can not retrieve any data from the request.form() method.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253142/how-to-post-a-page-from-asp-net-to-classic-asp)?

Comment: you are posting a form to an .aspx page then do some checking and send it back to the Client to then post it with JavaScript to an .asp page??? why not post the data to .asp directly after the checking?

Comment: @ulluoink, I think what you mentioned is exactly what i'm trying to do?  I have a quick and easy function attached to the Click event of a button that does some quick validation, which is much more easily completed via .NET, if that is successful I want to post to data to the .asp page.  as you said "why not post the data to .asp directly after the checking?" that's what I don't know how to accomplish.

Comment: @RickS I tried going through that but I still can't seem to retrieve the data on the classic asp page, not sure if it's possible

Comment: Have you tried creating a very minimal test.  An aspx page with one field sending it to a new asp classic page?  Did you do any debugging to make sure your sending the information in the correct format?  Did you try using [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to help with this?  That's about all I can suggest at this point.

Comment: @NickG well then just post it but not with JavaScript... post it from the Server side after your checking by using one of the several .NET classes. like HttpWebRequest or so

Answer (score 0):

post the values after the checking like so:

```
string remoteUrl = "http://your/url/of/classic.asp";

string firstName = "Luke";

string lastName = "Skywalker";



ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

string data = string.Format("FirstName={0}&LastName={1}", firstName, lastName);

byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(data);

HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(remoteUrl);

httpRequest.Method = "POST";

httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

httpRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

using (Stream stream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())

{

    stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

    stream.Close();

}
```